# discord bot that catches all dm's and send it to webhook

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to create a bot with discord js v13 that catches all messages from dm and send it to webhook and after admin give command /reply text bot sending back admin message to a guy that wroten message to bot, i dont know how to do it, but i need it

Answer (score 2):

To create a discord bot I recommend you to use [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) and [discord.js](https://discord.js.org) lib.

### Get the DM

First of all you will have to use the parameter `partials: ["CHANNEL"]` in your client constructor to allow your bot to receive and read DM

You will have to add an handler on the `messageCreate` event

When the event is triggered check the message channel type, if it's DM store the the message (in an array for example) and send request to your webhook.

### Respond to command

Follow [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/creating-commands.htm) to setup your reply command (for example a /reply which take user as parameters)

When bot receive command (dig documentation on `interactionCreate` event if i good remember) get the right message in the array where you store received DM)

You are done